# Xinerama 3 displays can't have main display in the middle

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, xorg

I have 3 monitors running on 2 cards, they are all working as 3 seperate displays, however, if i move the main display from the left (0,0) i cannot drag to the left window as the mouse goes crazy and crashes my system (i have to restart x)

I would much prefer my main display to be in the centre.

Any help appreciated

Comment: What signifies the "main display" in linux? In windows it's the Start bar & desktop icons & the screen that fullscreen games appear on, but you can change all of those in most linux desktop environments.